# How do I include ngAria in and Angular 2 application?

Tags: angularjs

This module seems very useful

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAria

How do I include the module in a Angular 2 app?

Comment: The link that you have provided tells you exactly how to include it.

Comment: You don't. Angular 1 and Angular 2 are different frameworks.

Comment: Do you know if there is an equivalent module in Angular 2?