# ARIA Accessibility in Angular 2 and 4

Tags: angular, accessibility, wai-aria

I have been manually including ARIA attributes in my component templates when I came across the angular-aria module: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAria

However, this is for AngularJS. Is there any equivalent module for Angular 2 and 4 which silently injects aria attributes on components at runtime?

I have looked at this question: [How do I include ngAria in and Angular 2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39257796/how-do-i-include-ngaria-in-and-angular-2-application) but it doesn't seem to have an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question has a short answer and a long one, let's see what are those?

Is there any **equivalent module** for Angular 2 and 4 which **silently** injects aria attributes on components at runtime?

Let's first refer to the KB for AngularJs:

> Using ngAria is as simple as requiring the ngAria module in your
>   application. ngAria hooks into standard AngularJS directives and
>   quietly injects accessibility support into your application at
>   runtime.

As Angular 2 has tried to have a built-in support for [ARIA](https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/), there is no such equivalent module needed, and there is no supplementary one which I'm aware of.

So, Yes, it's implicitly supported, and No, there is no such a module (required).

Accessibility use cases for Angular include, at least: (Quoted from [Marcy Sutton](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1878))

- Handling aria-disabled, aria-required, and aria-checked for custom
  controls
- Handling aria-* value attributes on custom controls using ngModel
- Discouraging click events on non-semantic div elements (could be done
  through documentation)
- Text alternatives: Labels for form controls, alt for images

You can simply investigate the above by inspecting the rendered output of your Angular template.

Final Note: It should be considered, anyway, that still complying manually with the rules of ARIA use are required, which is regardless of the version of the angular(JS or 2+) being use; e.g., avoiding to assign the click events to non-semantic elements, or embedding a giving label to elements which are not [labelable](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#labelable-element).